# Processing error with JSON data retrieved from yahoo weather

Tags: ios, json, swift

Im learning on how to write iOS code and I'm trying to write a weather application. Part of the JSON code that I retrieve from yahoo weather is:

```
      `"forecast":[
              {  
                 "code":"24",
                 "date":"2 Mar 2015",
                 "day":"Mon",
                 "high":"39",
                 "low":"16",
                 "text":"Partly Cloudy/Wind"
              }
         ]`
```

But for some reason, that part of the code has "[" and "]" symbol in it. Therefore my code is not able to get the data and store it in the NSDictionary. The iOS swift code I use to get data is:

```
               `if let forecast = item["forecast"] as? NSDictionary{

                        let highDay: AnyObject = forecast["high"]!
                        let lowDay: AnyObject = forecast["low"]!


                        high = String(highDay as NSString)
                        self.high.extend("˚")
                        println(high)

                        low = String(lowDay as NSString)
                        self.low.extend("˚")
                    }`
```

Im not having any issues with processing data blocks that doesn't have the "[" and "]" symbols. But I couldn't figure out this one. Are there any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: [] means it is an array not a dictionary. forecast[0] will give you the dictionary

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: use swiftjson for more simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forecast:[...] indicates that you are in a dictionary.  That value for the forecast key in that dictionary `item["forecast"]` is not a dictionary, but an array.  In JSON, [ ] is an array and { } is a dictionary.

In your exampled, the forecast array has only on item which is a dictionary.  To get it you could try:

```
if let forecastArray = item["forecast"] as? NSArray {
    if let forecast = forecastArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
    }
}
```